# Fully contain overlapping events in fullcalendar.io

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.io to show a series of slots that contain appointments. Currently, it just shows a the appointment slots and some images as part of the description of the event like

[image: here].

What I'd like to do is something like the following:

[image]

Each line item in those yellow boxes will need to have a hover tooltip and be clickable to run some arbitrary event.

In order to do that, I've played around with a few options:

1. Extend the description field of the event to contain divs that have onclick events (calendar events will have movement/resizing disabled). These onclick events will execute some javascript behaviour.
2. Create multiple events, one for the background, and one for each foreground event - however, they must be fully enclosed in the background event, which as shown [here](http://fullcalendar.io/views/basicDay/) (after clicking "Day") they do not entirely overlap.

Is there a best practice or built in function for having clickable items **ON** the events?

Thanks!
James

**UPDATE**

In the eventRender behaviour, you can manually update the CSS of the element to shift it. Allow overlaps, set the Z-Index manually if you need to, and use something like this:

```
$(element).css({"width":"50px", "margin-left":"-100px"})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an eventRender callback which can be used to modify the event any way we want. Check out the full calendar documentation.

Comment: I did see that and that's how I'm showing the data in the first image, by using .html(..) for element.find('.fc-content'). I was hoping there was a way to allow events to exist completely over other events - for example, two events, one from 1-5pm and the other from 2-4pm would overlap, without jutting out to the side as shown in the "basicDay" demo I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty messy to do because you need a way to handle overlapping events that *don't* contain each other at the same time. Or if it overlaps with two events, which one does it go into? And a million more edge cases. Bleh.

I can give you a basic algorithm for something similar and more robust.

### Parent/Child Events

- Give child events a parent ID.
- When child events are rendered in `eventRender`, clone and save the element, then return false to not render it.
- In `eventAfterAllRender`, add the saved elements to the relevant parent events.